# Where is the system menu for Desktop Ver 20.04.1

Tags: wireless, location

I am a first time Linux  users but a wide experience in computers and OS. I loaded Ubuntu Linux 20.04.1 for the first time,  I want to setup my wireless connection.  I have been trying to find the "System Menu".  All of the help screens say it is in the upper right corner but all i see up there is a speaker, power and a drop arrow.  When I select the drop arrow I see a settings selection.  When I select it I get a settings menu but I see now way to get to a "System Menu" from there.

Regards Annie

Comment: Maybe you are using some old manuals. The "settings" should be good to setup Wi-Fi. But I suspect you'll need some drivers, etc.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the same problem. The system menu exists in the older version of Ubuntu, but I guess you want to install the Wi-Fi driver. If your Wi-Fi router is RTL or something similar, you can search your Wi-Fi name using this:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

I was able to solve this problem as follows:

1. Buy a new (inexpensive) Wi-Fi adapter.
2. Install an older version of Ubuntu, and before installation you can check if your Wi-Fi is safely connected or not. You can find the older version of Ubuntu in this link: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/

When I tried to troubleshoot this issue, I tried to install the Wi-Fi driver but it failed. Then I tried Ubuntu 19.10 and it was fine for me.

This problem originally happened about 8 months ago. Today I re-installed Ubuntu 20.04.01 and now there are no Wi-Fi problems.